# s3cmd not "Getting" the distcp jar file

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, s3cmd

Hi guys : I'm trying to get the s3 distcp jar file via s3, in an EMR cluster :

```
s3cmd get s3://eu-west-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/s3distcp/1.0.1/s3distcp.jar
```

However, the "get" command is not working:

```
ERROR: Skipping libs/s3distcp/: No such file or directory
```

This file exists in other s3 regions, also, so I even have tried :

```
s3cmd get s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/s3distcp/1.0.1/s3distcp.jar
```

But the ecommand still fails. But alas -- this .jar file CLEARLY exists, when we run "s3cmd ls", we can see it listed. See below for the details (example with the eu-west region) :

```
hadoop@ip-10-58-254-82:/mnt$ s3cmd ls s3://eu-west-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/s3distcp/
Bucket 'eu-west-1.elasticmapreduce':
2012-06-01 00:32   3614287   s3://eu-west-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/s3distcp/1.0.1/s3distcp.jar
2012-06-05 17:14   3615026   s3://eu-west-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/s3distcp/1.0.2/s3distcp.jar
2012-06-12 20:52   1893078   s3://eu-west-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/s3distcp/1.0.3/s3distcp.jar
2012-06-20 01:17   1893140   s3://eu-west-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/s3distcp/1.0.4/s3distcp.jar
2012-06-27 21:27   1893846   s3://eu-west-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/s3distcp/1.0.5/s3distcp.jar
2012-03-15 21:21   3613175   s3://eu-west-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/s3distcp/1.0/s3distcp.jar
2012-06-27 21:27   1893846   s3://eu-west-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/s3distcp/1.latest/s3distcp.jar
```

The above seems to confirm that, in fact the file exists.

**How can I enable the "get" command to work for this file ? **

Comment: Here is the full command output, with the --debug output as requested below :  http://pastebin.com/EyV2RJBh

Comment: Here is the strace output from running the command under strace : http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=CvSfRN0u

Answer (score 1):

The jar is just working fine, can you paste the error message you are getting after the get command?

```
:s3cmd ls s3://eu-west-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/s3distcp/1.0.1/s3distcp.jar

2012-06-01 00:32   3614287   s3://eu-west-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/s3distcp/1.0.1/s3distcp.jar

:s3cmd get s3://eu-west-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/s3distcp/1.0.1/s3distcp.jar

s3://eu-west-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/s3distcp/1.0.1/s3distcp.jar -> ./s3distcp.jar  [1 of 1]
 3614287 of 3614287   100% in    3s  1008.86 kB/s  done
```

Comment: ERROR: Skipping libs/s3distcp/: No such file or directory

Comment: Can you paste the full output here, including the get command and the full output, even passing the --debug parameter to the command. You might want to use github/gist for the full output for readability.

Comment: Your path is incorrect: Correct: s3://eu-west-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/s3distcp/1.0.1/s3distcp.jar Incorrect: s3://eu-west-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/s3distcp/s3distcp.jar

Comment: hmmm still no luck : hadoop@ip-10-249-62-84:/mnt/var/log/bootstrap-actions/3$ s3cmd get s3://eu-west-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/s3distcp/1.0.1/s3distcp.jar
ERROR: Skipping libs/s3distcp/1.0.1/s3distcp.jar: No such file or directory